# What does the "ip" status in the aptitude package list mean?

Tags: aptitude

What does the *ip* status in the aptitude package list mean? For example:

```
$ aptitude search some_package
ip some_package description
```

Answer (score 1):

The status means that the package is installed and will be deleted by the `aptitude install` command (without arguments).

Aptitude can put off actions by executing the acting command with the *--schedule-only* option.

```
# aptitude --schedule-only purge some_package
```

After issuing the command the package won't be uninstalled right away — it will be put off and get the *p* flag in the package list:

```
# aptitude search some_package
ip some_package description
```

To perform all pending actions one should execute the following command:

```
# aptitude install
```

To cancel the pending purge you should use the *keep* action:

```
# aptitude keep some_package
```

After issuing the command the *p* flag will be deleted from the package list.

Answer (score 0):

The manpage for aptitude says:

> Unless you pass the -F option, the output of aptitude search will look something like this:
>
> [...]
>
> Each search result is listed on a separate line. The first character of each line indicates the current state of the package: the most common states are p,
>   meaning that no trace of the package exists on the system, c, meaning that the package was deleted but its configuration files remain on the system, i,
>   meaning that the package is installed, and v, meaning that the package is virtual. The second character indicates the stored action (if any; otherwise a
>   blank space is displayed) to be performed on the package, with the most common actions being i, meaning that the package will be installed, d, meaning that
>   the package will be deleted, and p, meaning that the package and its configuration files will be removed. If the third character is A, the package was
>   automatically installed.
>
> For a complete list of the possible state and action flags, see the section “Accessing Package Information” in the aptitude reference guide. To customize
>   the output of search, see the command-line options -F and --sort.

-> "some_package" is already installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

The package is installed and is going to be purged.  Check out [this](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s02s02.html) part of the aptitude users guide for a really good explanation of the flags.